# share business objects between webservice

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I want to expose on wso2 esb or wso2-as a set of webservices sharing 
the same business object model.
What is the best way to do it with wso2 and DeveloperStudio ?

Tks
Nicolas

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on your usecase? This is too abstract to provide an answer.

Comment: I need to provide a set of webservices sharing the same object model.For example, bank operations sharing the same banking model. So, if we want to use WSO2-AS by publishing web services via AAR or spring service, how to share the library between several services (jar library for example). Other solution is to embed all web service inside a WAR but I think we skip by the way the web service orientation of WSO2, so my question is what is the best way to do it with WSO2 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the relevant jar inside CARBON_HOME/repository/components/lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

Just deploy all your services(*.aar or spring service) in wso2AS and keep your libraries in 
repository/components/lib folder.
Wso2esb is not used to host services, rather it is used as mediation engine.